# How to add slashes between the chars of a String?

Tags: vba

I am trying to add slashes between characters in a string, e. g. hello -> h/e/l/l/o

I tried to use Replace(string, "", "/") but the String remained unchanged.

Comment: According to your code, you are triying to replace nothing ("") to "/" , thats why nothing is happening, so try first for example go over string with an iterator, then in each pair index, put the slash. Try my suggestion if you can't i will put and answer, but first you need to try.

Comment: Did you try?, you can answer your own question.

Comment: Try `Replace(StrConv(string, vbUnicode), Chr$(0), "/")`

Comment: @wqw - I had been thinking along those lines but with split and join. e.g. `join(split(StrConv("hello", vbUnicode), Chr$(0)), "/")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub Main
dim initial_text as string
dim final_text as string 
initial_text = "hello"
final_text = ""

Dim i As Integer

For i = 1 To len(initial_text)

   if i =  len(initial_text) then
      final_text = final_text + Mid(initial_text,i,1)
   else 
      final_text = final_text + Mid(initial_text,i,1) + "/"
   end if

Next i
   msgbox final_text
End Sub
```

**EDIT**

For study porpuse, I add another answer based on comments from (The next answer is a good answer too):

```
Dim s As String
s = "Hello"
```

@wqw

```
Debug.Print Left(Replace(StrConv(s, vbUnicode), Chr$(0), "/"), Len(s) * 2 - 1)
```

@Jeeped

```
Debug.Print Left(Join(Split(StrConv(s, vbUnicode), Chr$(0)), "/"), Len(s) * 2 - 1)
```

Comment: Thanks, I just came up with a solution and it's the same as yours :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an emulation of `preg_replace` function from PHP that I'm using which allows a simple regex to do the job. The look-ahead part gets rid of the last slash too.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Form_Load()
    Dim s As String
    s = "Hello"
    Debug.Print preg_replace("(.)(?=.)", "$1/", s)
End Sub

Public Function preg_replace(sPattern As String, sReplace As String, sText As String) As String
    Dim lIdx            As Long

    With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        .Global = True
        If Left$(sPattern, 1) = "/" Then
            lIdx = InStrRev(sPattern, "/")
            .Pattern = Mid$(sPattern, 2, lIdx - 2)
            .IgnoreCase = (InStr(lIdx, sPattern, "i") > 0)
            .MultiLine = (InStr(lIdx, sPattern, "m") > 0)
        Else
            .Pattern = sPattern
        End If
        preg_replace = .Replace(sText, sReplace)
    End With
End Function
```